# get gson json element as string

Tags: javascript, java, android

i am trying to get an array in android from this gson element but I can't.

this is my gson element

```
  Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load("http://sss8/web/public/lda/10")
                .asJsonArray()

                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonArray result) {
                        Log.d("LOADDD",String.valueOf(result.get(0)));

                        }
                });
```

the result, but I want it seperately like reachable from result[0] result [1] and soo

```
05-07 19:17:42.807 28166-28166/comsssss D/LOADDD: {"peopl":0.0029832935560859,"music":0.0020883054892601,"smartphon":0.0017899761336516,"girl":0.0017899761336516,"record":0.001491646778043,"world":0.001491646778043,"sound":0.001491646778043,"subject":0.001491646778043,"believ":0.0011933174224344,"american":0.0011933174224344}
```

Comment: What does `result.get(0)` look like if you don't explicitly turn it into a string?

Comment: you can see it on debug, no its json element..... want to reach first people: 0.002 value with result[0] like that

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to `onCompleted`:

```
      if (result != null) { 

        for (int i=0;i<result.length();i++){ 

         Log.d("LOADDD",String.valueOf(result.get(i)));
   } 
}
```